# How can I create an event listener that responds to Facebook news feed page (DOM) updates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension, listener

I am trying to build a chrome extension (JavaScript) that responds to new posts loading on the front page of Facebook (news feed). This can happen when you scroll down or when the page automatically updates because enough time has passed. I considered setInterval but the user experience won't be as nice. I also considered using a. DOM4 mutation observer but I couldn't make it work quite right. Is there a better solution? Should I look into a way to track requests?

Comment: DOM mutation observers are probably the way to go. You should include what you've tried, and then we could possibly pinpoint the problem. As-is, this question is not a good one.

Comment: Did you look in the Facebook API?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that could be against the facebook policy,
you should try with the APi to get better results.

You should call - me/home with appropriate access token.
You may try this here - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer (click get access token to give the read_stream permission ).

Here is a link to the Fb documentation - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/home